# "Good" edge-colorings

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $n >1$ be an integer, and suppose $G = (V,E)$ is a simple undirected graph with $V = \{1,\ldots,n\}$. For $v\in V$ set $N(v) = \{w\in V: \{v,w\} \in E\}$.

It is known by [Vizing's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem) that the edges of $G$ can be [colored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) with $\Delta(G)+1$ colors (where $\Delta(\cdot)$ denotes the maximum degree), and of course we have $\Delta(G)+1 \leq n$.

We call an [edge-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) $c:E\to \{1,\ldots,n\}$ **good** if for all $x\neq y\in V$ with $\{x,y\} \in E$ we have $c(\{x,y\}) \in N(x)\cup N(y).$

> Does every graph $G=(\{1,\ldots,n\},E)$ have a good edge-coloring?

Comment: I assume you actually want $V=\{1,\dots, n\}$ and not just $|V|=n$?

Comment: Oh - that's right, thanks Tony for noticing my error! I have just edited the post accordingly.

Comment: It immediately follows from the edge choosability conjecture, but maybe is weak enough to be provable.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : How does it follow? The lists here have different sizes.

Comment: @TimothyChow ops, indeed! I wonder whether edge choosability conjecture implies that any graph is edges-choosable if a list for edge $e=uv$ contains $\max(\deg u,\deg v)+1$ colors. I tried a bit tricks with adding extra vertices, but have not succeed.

Comment: I confess that I don't even see how to prove that the edge-coloring number of $G$ is at most $\max_{\{x,y\}\in E} |N(x) \cup N(y)|$. Maybe someone should provide a proof of that first?

Comment: @TimothyChow This is a very good point - I suggest you ask this as a question of its own!

Comment: @TimothyChow Oh - can't you prove your assertion by noting that the edge coloring number is always $\Delta$ or $\Delta+1$? -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem . I wrote this in a hurry, and I might be completely wrong

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen : Ah, yes, of course. So maybe one should look at algorithms for Vizing's theorem to see if any of them can be adapted for this problem.

Comment: Am I wrong? This coloring depend to the vertex labelling?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a solution yet, but I propose to call this a **local** edge coloring instead of a **good** one.

Basically, the nodes are colored with the colors 1 to n here, and the edges should be colored with the same colors. In addition to that, the set of colors that are allowed for an edge $\{u,v\}$ is restricted to $N(u) \cup N(v)$, i.e. to the colors that are locally available in the neighborhood of $u$ and $v$.

We could call an edge coloring **strongly local**, if the palette for edge $\{u,v\}$ is restricted to $u$ and $v$ themselves, and **local**, if it is only restricted to $N(u) \cup N(v)$.

Examples:

- Any circular graph $C_n$ has a strongly local edge coloring.
- The complete graph $K_4$ does not have a strongly local edge coloring.
- Any $K_n$ has a local edge coloring, because $N(u) \cup N(v) = V$, so the locality condition does not impose a real restriction in complete graphs.